# Grails Spring Security Slow Startup

Tags: grails, spring-security

Environment :

```
Intel Core 2 duo, 3 gig RAM
Ubuntu 9.10, Grails 1.3.5, Spring security plugin 1.1.2
JVM Parameters : -Xms512m  -Xmx1024m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Starting an application that uses the grails spring security plugin is very slow. I found this reported [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1615). The work around suggests setting the anonymous key as that seems to be the slow down due to `SecureRandom` - "set a key manually using " .

I set this within `Config.groovy` to no avail.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.anonymous.key="someuniquekey"
```

Where a number was used for `someuniquekey`. It still takes **forever** (~30 seconds) to get past the `Configuring Spring Security...` message.

Any ideas? Am I setting this in the wrong place or the wrong way?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: two further questions regarding this: 1) what computer are you using (CPU, RAM, OS) and 2) are you using any JVM memory parameters?

Comment: You should really upgrade the plugin to 1.1.2.  Would be a good idea to upgrade Grails version as well because it has some troublesome bugs that will bite you later, depending on how far into dev you are and how much control you have over upgrades.

Comment: The question has been updated with more environmental info. Nothing fancy for the JVM parameters, just some normal memory stuff. I upgraded to spring security 1.1.2, but didn't see any noticeable startup improvement. Probably needed to do that anyway. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 22 Miscellaneous Properties

http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html

the key should be

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.anon.key
```

But I try it, even not no change after set.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer! That answered how to set the key, but I didn't necessarily see a startup improvement either. I did notice another property "active" that I set to false and it did improve startup time considerably. Another thing I noticed was the schema generation was taking some time. Removing the "dbCreate" in DataSource also helped speed startup. Of course those properties need to be set properly for production. But at least there's an acceptable development solution. Thanks again! Steve

Answer (score 1):

You can set the next var in Config.groovy

```
environments.development.searchable.bulkIndexOnStartup = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem is not totally related to Spring Security,
since I install Searchable, and has some amount of data inside the db,
the slow startup mainly due from the Searchable build index, when startup.

You can find the solution for the Searchable startup setup here,

http://www.grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+FAQ